# Fewer line to count max int in array on Kotlin and faster than O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I wonder if there a better way or idiomatic way to count the max int in an array with Kotlin and faster than O(nlogn)?

This code gives O(n) but I feel like it too long

```
fun countMax(n: Int, ar: Array<Int>): Int {
   val max = ar.max();
    var countMax = 0
    for(i in ar)
        if(i==max)
            countMax++

                return countMax
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val n = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()

    val ar = scan.nextLine().split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()

    val result = birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar)

    println(result)
}
```

Sorting then counting got nlogn

val input: Scanner = if (inputFile.exists()) Scanner(inputFile) else Scanner(System.`in`)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  input.nextLine()
  val nums = input.nextLine().split(' ').map { it.toLong() }.sorted()
  val s = nums.takeLastWhile { it == nums.last() }.size
  print(s)
}
```

I wonder there is a shorter code and perform faster than O(nlogn)

Comment: define `better way` please, are you interested in performance or line count?

Comment: Lets say Line count

Comment: then something like `ar.filter{it == ar.max()}.size` should work

Comment: @IlyaBursov That would be O(n^2), right? Just because line count is the priority doesn't mean you should resort to that.

Comment: @gdejohn yes, time N^2, and N additional space, horrible solution, but 1 line :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
fun countMax(ar: Array<Int>) = 
    ar.max().let { max -> ar.count { it == max } }
```

Calc the maximum with `max` and then use `count` to get the number of occurrences of that max in the array.

Alternatively, group the values, extract the group with max as its key, and map to the size:

```
fun countMax(ar: Array<Int>) = 
    ar.groupBy { it }.maxBy { it.key }?.value?.size
```

Comment: Another, a little bit more efficient way to do that with grouping: `ar.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().maxBy { it.key }?.value`

Comment: @hotkey thanks, even more efficient than the first example?

Comment: Nope, it's a bit more efficient than the second example, since it does not store the groups, but it's definitely slower than your first example.

Answer (score 1):

[Fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) the array, where the initial value is a pair holding [`Int.MIN_VALUE`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/-m-i-n_-v-a-l-u-e.html) and a count of `0`, and the operation returns a new pair incrementing the count if the given element is equal to the first number of the given pair (which represents the biggest number seen so far), or if the element is greater than the first number then it returns a pair holding that element and a count of `1`, or if the element is less than the first number then it simply returns that same pair.

This approach only traverses the array once, minimizing the number of comparisons performed.